# Append from dict to list?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this dictionary containing data:

```
{1000: 'brown', 4000: 'yellow', 2000: 'yellow', 3000: 'blue'}
```

My dictionary, however, has a lot more data, but this is the structure. The key is unique but the value is not as it may apply to several keys and i have used a loop earlier on to make sure no duplicate keys are in there.

What i want to to is to sort the dictionary into lists/dicts/tupels whatever works. So one list for all brown, one for all yellow, and one for all blue (there are only three colors, so i need three lists). Kinda like this:

```
brown_list = [1000, 5000, 7000]
yellow_list = [4000, 2000, 8000]
blue_list = [3000, 9000, 10000]
```

I attempted to do it this way (color_name is my original dictionary):

```
for color in color_name:
   if color_name == 'brown'
      brown_list.append color_name
```

Unfortunately this doesnt work. I have tried to read up on dictionaries and appending from them but im not really getting it. Any tips on how to go about splitting the dictionary into different lists depending on the value of the dict?

Comment: You "used a loop earlier on to make sure no duplicate keys are in [the dict]". That's not how dictionaries work. They cannot have duplicate keys.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesnt work"? What specific issue are you encountering? Is the invalid syntax in your third snippet a copy-paste mistake, or is that your actual code?

Comment: Yes, ur absolutely right, i lost myself in my words. 

My example syntax was just me showing i didnt know how to go about it, so yes, my code, but i knew it was fruitless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to loop through both keys and values of your dictionary
- `append` is a method; method calls require parentheses
- Put a colon after the if statement

```
for number, color in your_dictionary.items():
   if color == 'brown':
      brown_list.append(number)
   elif color == 'yellow':
      ...
```

Comment: I think they are trying to grab the keys from the dictionary based on the value? Maybe I am wrong on what your code is doing.

Comment: Yes, I fixed it.

Comment: This actually worked very well, got exactly what i wanted. Thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

You should really reflect your structure with an easier access method: another dict, keyed by color:

```
>>> value_dict = {1000: 'brown', 4000: 'yellow', 2000: 'yellow', 3000: 'blue'}
>>> set(value_dict.values())
{'brown', 'blue', 'yellow'}
>>> color_dict = {}
>>> for color in set(value_dict.values()):
    color_dict[color] = [v for v, c in value_dict.items() if c == color]
>>> color_dict
{'brown': [1000], 'blue': [3000], 'yellow': [4000, 2000]}
```

If you want to get uber-Pythonic, you can collapse the transformation to a single line, a list comprehension inside a dict comprehension:

```
color_dict{color: [v for v, c in value_dict.items() if c == color]
              for color in set(value_dict.values())
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an output dict whose keys are the colors and whose associated values are the list of data values associated with each color.

For example:

```
dict1 = {1000: 'brown', 4000: 'yellow', 2000: 'yellow', 3000: 'blue'}
dict2 = {}

for k,v in dict1.items():
    dict2[v] = [*dict2.get(v, []), k]

print(dict2)
```

Result is: `{'brown': [1000], 'yellow': [4000, 2000], 'blue': [3000]}`

This scales better for additional colors. Instead of `blue_list`, you would use `dict2['blue']`.

Comment: yeah probably wiser to use this since i have quite a few colors and rows

Answer (score 1):

Store the numbers in a dictionary, and use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to create it:

```
from collections import defaultdict

color_name = {1000: 'brown', 4000: 'yellow', 2000: 'yellow', 3000: 'blue', 5000: 'brown', }
color_to_nums = defaultdict(list)

for num, color in color_name.items():
    color_to_nums[color] += [num]

# Optional: convert back into regular dictionary
color_to_nums = dict(color_to_nums)

print(color_to_nums)
# {'brown': [1000, 5000], 'yellow': [4000, 2000], 'blue': [3000]}
```